# Python dictionary access ends up as a typeerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror

I'm trying to change an specific part of a dictionary, using Python 3.9 and VS Code terminal, but in change part,

```
 elif choice=='2':
                    part_name = input('Which part are you willing to change?\n(CaSe SeNsEtIvE)\nname--age--score--ID? ')
                    if part_name in list_keys:
                        new_value = input("New value? ")
                    else:
                        print('part not found!')
                        ending()
                    listname[final[part_name]] = new_value
                    ending()
```

it returns an error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when I try to access the value in the dict. What's the problem? Note that `strip_name.delspace` is a module of mine that removes spaces in an string.

```
import os, msvcrt, strip_name
list_keys, listname = ['name', 'age', 'score', 'ID'], {'AsgharAkbari':{'name':"Asghar Akbari",'age': 28,'score': 86,'ID':23897},'amirrezavavsari':{'name':"amirreza vavsari",'age':15,'score': 94,'ID':53614}}
   

 def delete():
        os.system('cls')
        print("which student are you willing to delete? (print back to go back)")
      
            del_name = input("enter fullname(CaSe SeNsEtIvE): ")
       
            final = strip_name.delspace(del_name)
            if final in listname.keys():
                choice = input('1- Delete fully\n2-change a part')
                if choice=='1':
                    del listname[final]
                    ending()
                elif choice=='2':
                    part_name = input('Which part are you willing to change?\n(CaSe SeNsEtIvE)\nname--age--score--ID? ')
                    if part_name in list_keys:
                        new_value = input("New value? ")
                    else:
                        print('part not found!')
                        ending()
                    listname[final[part_name]] = new_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  `listname[final[part_name]]`, `final` is a string, and you are trying to index it with `part_name`, which is also a string. Maybe you meant `listname[final][part_name]`, which accesses the value of the key `part_name` in the dictionary at key `final` in `listname`?

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot. So it's like multidimensional arrays in C++?

Comment: @SorooshYadollahPour You're welcome! A dictionary in python is like unordered map in c++. Or multidimensional map, since you have a dictionary containing dictionaries.

Comment: NO NO NO I meant the calling part.

Answer (score 0):

`part_name` is recognized as a string because in Python 3 `input` does not check the data type. The solution would be to covnert data from input to integers:

```
part_name = int(input('foo'))
```